# Request the get email address permission in android facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
 private void onClickLogin() {
        tracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("menu_click","Fbconnect","connectFB_" + Utility.getLocale(getActivity()),null).build());
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
            //session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info","email")).setCallback(statusCallback));
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setPermissions(Arrays.asList("email")).setCallback(statusCallback));
        } else {
            Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), this, true, statusCallback);
        }
    }
```

I am working on facebook custom login, the problem is when I click on the login button, the first time it ask user whether to allow the app to get their info, friend list, email.

But, if I clicked cancel and click the login button later, it will ask the user whether the app to get their info and friend list only , without asking about the email. How to fix this ? Thanks